# How to accurately classify text with a lot of potential values using scikit?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a variety of blacklisted terms I want identified within a corpus of text paragraphs. Each term is around 1 - 5 words long and contains certain keywords I do not want in my corpus of documents. If a term or something similar to it is identified in the corpus I want it removed from my corpus.

Removal aside, I am struggling with accurately identifying these terms in my corpus. I am using scikit-learn and have tried two seperate approaches:

1. A MultinomialNB classification approach using tf-idf vector features with a mix of blacklisted terms and clean terms used as training data.
2. A OneClassSVM approach where just the blacklisted keywords are used as training data and any text passed in that does not seem to resemble the blacklisted terms are considered outliers.

Here is the code for my OnceClassSVm approach:

```
df = pd.read_csv("keyword_training_blacklist.csv")

keywords_list = df['Keyword']

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb', max_df=0.75, min_df=1, ngram_range=(1, 5))),
    # strings to token integer counts
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False, norm='l2')),  # integer counts to weighted TF-IDF scores
    ('clf', OneClassSVM(nu=0.1, kernel="rbf", gamma=0.1)),  # train on TF-IDF vectors w/ Naive Bayes classifier
])

kf = KFold(len(keywords_list), 8)
for train_index, test_index in kf:
    # make training and testing datasets
    X_train, X_test = keywords_list[train_index], keywords_list[test_index]

    pipeline.fit(X_train)  # Train classifier using training data and labels
    predicted = pipeline.predict(X_test)
    print(predicted[predicted == 1].size / predicted.size)

csv_df = pd.read_csv("corpus.csv")

testCorpus = csv_df['Terms']

testCorpus = testCorpus.drop_duplicates()


for s in testCorpus:
    if pipeline.predict([s])[0] == 1:
        print(s)
```

In practice, I am getting many false positives when I try to pass in my corpus to the algorithm. My blacklisted term training data stands at around 3000 terms. Does the size of my training data need to be increased further or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What are your actual features - just individual words? Have you tried using pairs of adjacent words instead? Also, what do you mean by "a term or something similar to it" - semantically similar, or within some editing distance, or something else?

Comment: are you trying to remove documents containing these terms? or the terms themselves? why don't you use regexp?

Comment: I want to catch terms with similar spelling to those that are in my blacklist. A term would be a simple string such as "this is a term" and "loren ipsum". A blacklisted term would be "sexy girls" and I want to catch similar looking terms like "sexxy girls". I've looked up methods such as Levenshtein distance but I am unsure if they can be included ina ML algorithm. A regexp approach sounds obvious at first, but I have thousands of blacklisted terms and millions of terms to sort through, which explains my need for a ML approach.

Comment: 1) search for printable characters up to a certain length starting at, lets say, 3 characters
2) Use those printable characters as a new regex to match to your current strings list increasing the length of the regex on the string until it no longer matches?
3) If at some point it no longer matches your dictionary as a substring match go back to the last longest string with the highest % match and return the value?

Comment: Have you tried brute force removal first?  Regex removal or basic n-gram matching.   See how long it takes.  Then figure out your similarity problem.  If n-gram matching works reasonably fast (less than an hour?), then add in Levenshtein on top of that approach.  Setting a proper threshold for Levenshtein is the classic precision, recall problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `difflib` to identify closest match in the corpus to each of your black listed terms.

```
import difflib
from nltk.util import ngrams

words = corpus.split(' ') # split corpus to words based on spaces ( can be improved )

words_ngrams = [] # ngrams from 1 to 5 words
for n in range(1,6):
    words_ngrams.extend( ' '.join(ngrams(words, n)) )


to_delete = [] # will contain tuples (index, length) of matched terms to delete from corpus.
sim_rate = 0.8 # similarity rate
max_matches = 4 # maximum number of matches for each term
for term in terms:
    matches = difflib.get_close_matches(term,words_ngrams,n=max_matches,cutoff=sim_rate)
    for match in matches:
        to_delete.append( (corpus.index(match), len(match) ) )
```

You can also use `difflib.SequenceMatcher` if you want to get a score of similarity between terms and ngrams.